# Create a new binary variable based on whether previous variable is in a vector (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm have a list of responses to a question, and I need to create a new variable based on these responses categorising them into two categories. This is done based on which of two lists the responses appear in: one has all responses meant to be recoded into one category (ie the new variable having a value of 0), and the other contains all responses to be recoded in the new variable as 1.

I've tried to get this to work using a for loop which cycles through every row, tests the response variable, and assigns a new value to the new variable based on which list the response is in, but when I run it this assigns every row a value of 1 for the new variable, regardless of the old variable.

A reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(state = state.name)
# create the reference lists
AtoM <- df$state[1:26]
NtoZ <- df$state[27:50]

for (i in seq_along(df$state)) {
  if (df$state[i] %in% AtoM) {
    df$state.bin <- 0
  } else if (df$state[i] %in% NtoZ) {
    df$state.bin <- 1
  } else {
    df$state.bin <- NA
  }
}
View(df) # when the result is viewed, the new state.bin variable has a value of 1 for every row
```

It should be that the first 26 states get assigned a value of 0 for the new variable, but they're all assigned 1. But when I test `df$state[1] %in% AtoM`, it returns `TRUE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give an index for where in `df$state.bin` you want the value placed (`df$state.bin[i]`, just as you did with `df$state[i]`), and you also need to create a placeholder variable in your original `df`, which I did with `state.bin = 0`.

```r
df <- data.frame(state = state.name,
                 state.bin = 0)
# create the reference lists
AtoM <- df$state[1:26]
NtoZ <- df$state[27:50]

for (i in seq_along(df$state)) {
  if (df$state[i] %in% AtoM) {
    df$state.bin[i] <- 0
  } else if (df$state[i] %in% NtoZ) {
    df$state.bin[i] <- 1
  } else {
    df$state.bin[i] <- NA
  }
}

> df

            state state.bin
1         Alabama         0
2          Alaska         0
3         Arizona         0
4        Arkansas         0
5      California         0
6        Colorado         0
```

You could also use `dplyr`:

```r
df <- data.frame(state = state.name)
# create the reference lists
AtoM <- df$state[1:26]
NtoZ <- df$state[27:50]

df %>%
  mutate(state.bin = case_when(
    state %in% AtoM ~ 0,
    state %in% NtoZ ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))

            state state.bin
1         Alabama         0
2          Alaska         0
3         Arizona         0
4        Arkansas         0
5      California         0
6        Colorado         0
```

Comment: Aah thank you! This has worked for both my reproducible and actual data.